# Tomcat secure access

Tags: security, authentication, tomcat, client, web.xml

I have two Web Services (MyService and MyProtectedService). I want both going under the same port HTTPS but only the protected one to have client authentication (clientAuth=true).

All the security is working fine, but the problem is that the client auth is ON for both services, not only for the protected one. What I would like is remove the client auth for one of them, or apply the client auth to the other only.

Does anyone have any hint?  Thanks

In the web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected element</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/MyProtectedService</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

UPDATE:
I tried to divide the service in two constrains:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>OpenService</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/OpenService</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>protected</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/MyProtectedService</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    <login-config>
        <auth-metod>CLIENT-CERT</auth-metod>
    </login-config>
</security-constraint>
```

And have ClientAuth=false in server.xml.

But then I can access this without any client authentication:
https://MACHINE/MyProtectedService/MyProtectedService?wsdl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The approach is to have two separate *security constraints* even though the one for the public service has no constraint at all (neither a `auth-constraint` nor a `user-data-constraint`). It assumes that the two service have different URLs which is most likely the case:

```
<security-role>
    <role-name>ProtectedServiceRole</role-name>
</security-role>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Public Service</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/PublicService/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Protected Service</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/ProtectedService/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ProtectedServiceRole</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

The role name specified in the `auth-constraint` will trigger an authentication.

**Update:**

I'm afraid I haven't properly read your question and overlooked the certificate authentication part. Though I have used it in the past, I never had the mixed setup you require so I can only give some options what you could try next:

Currently you require the authentication on the transport level. That's to low-level and too early. Have you tried setting *clientAuth* to *false* and instead add the following lines to your web.xml:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Another approach would be to use two differnt ports for the two services. For that, you define two different *connectors* in the server.xml.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried this and I think there is something else involved because I'm still asked for the cert. If instead of https I use http:443 then I get strange characters. Any ideas?

Comment: @Codo, it seems like Tomcat is always asking for the client auth (server.xml is checked before web.xml, it makes sense), so I don't think what you mentioned can work... :-?

Comment: Thanks,@Codo. Apparently is not doing anything... See my update above in the question

Comment: @Codo, and for the different connectors...should it work? Because if I have one connector without clientAuth, it will still serve "MyProtectedService" won't it? Or is there a way to restrict the servlet inside the WAR application?

Comment: Two connectors were necessary (one HTTPS with clientAuth, the other HTTP) and then web.xml configuration for both servlets. Thanks @Codo