# Tomcat : matching port - application/servlet

Tags: security, tomcat, deployment, configuration, certificate

After my unsuccessful attempt with:
[Tomcat secure access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332966/tomcat-secure-access)

Does anyone know how I can run a single Tomcat instance serving one WAR (or specific servlet) over one port and another WAR (or specific servlet) under another?

(My objective is to have one servlet/app with client authentication and another one with no authentication at all. It seems rather strange to me that Tomcat is white or black: or everything is secured or nothing is).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up as many connectors as you wish within the server.xml:

```
<Connector port="80" redirectPort="8443"/>    
<Connector port="8080" redirectPort="8443"/>    
<Connector port="999" redirectPort="8443"/>
<Connector port="8443" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
               enableLookups="false" disableUploadTimeout="true"
               acceptCount="100" scheme="https" secure="true"
               clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" />
```

You can also set up secure / HTTPS ports. Then you can instruct you app to only allow secure connections(hence the purpose of the redirect port) or add code to find out which port is being used by the connection (a bit hacky).

However, an easier approach would just be to have multiple Tomcat installations - one setup and running your secure app, the other doing the non-secure apps - each running on their own ports.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I think your 1st suggestion is not really valid, because I had no way to say "this servlet has clientAuth=true, and this other = false".If I specify "false" for all of them, I have no way in the web.xml to say "clientAuth=true". Installing and running two Tomcats is an easy solution as you pointed out, but not really affordable on my system. I'd like to use even the same WAR and don't want to waste resources with 2 app instances. I can't believe Tomcat didn't think of this configuration!

Comment: It is valid. Simply have one app using HTTPS, setting `      <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>` and the other on the standard port (both could point to port 80 - the client auth app will be forced onto the secure port).

Comment: but how do you enable the client authentication? I could use a single port and configure web.xml to have different access for the two servlets, I agree. But with "confidential", you just assure that one of the servlets will use HTTPS, no clientAuth... I tried to configure the client Auth in the web.xml but it didn't work :(

Comment: One port uses HTTPS with client auth, the other uses HTTP.

Comment: Well, in the end I couldn't make it work as I wanted but I solved the problem: Create 2 connectors, one with HTTPS clientAuth and the other HTTP (I wanted this to be HTTPS as well but didn't work). BUT no redirections were needed. Then configure the "transport-guarantee" and the "auth-method" for both servlets and it's done!

Comment: It's a shame you couldn't run your app on two HTTPS ports (one with client auth) - but there's no simple way to stop someone accessing the app from the undesired port. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have to setup VirtualHosts in Tomcat for each port (see http://www.ex-parrot.com/~pete/tomcat-vhost.html) and deploy each war in the designated virtual host. That should do the trick.