# Basic Authentication for WEBService by AXIS2

Tags: java, apache-axis

i am using Eclispe, i am creating dynamic project in that, i am also creating stub by using axis2, while accessing url i need to do some basic AUTHENTICATE, how to do this in java

Comment: Can you please either accept an answer or rephrase your question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use security constraints in your web.xml (assuming you are using Tomcat to deploy).

This means that you can filter on who is allowed to access the web service.

Question here gives a general insight into it [Tomcat secure access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6332966/tomcat-secure-access)

[Tomcat : Bypass basic Authentication for Specified IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631974/tomcat-bypass-basic-authentication-for-specified-ip-address)

You can use either username and password, or filter by IP